# Append block in blob service python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

Azure blob storage service with Append Block in python azure module doesn't work. When i tried to modify the module it shows the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 106, in exec_file
    exec_code(code, file, global_variables)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.1\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 82, in exec_code
    exec(code_obj, global_variables)
  File "E:\Finons\Sankar\Source\Source\WebsiteTracking\testing.py", line 15, in<module>
  blob_service.append_block_blob_from_file(containername,filename,filepath,None)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blobservice.py", line 2723, in append_block_blob_from_file
  x_ms_lease_id,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\blobservice.py", line 851, in put_blob    self._perform_request(request)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\storageclient.py", line 179,  in _perform_request
    _storage_error_handler(ex)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\azure\storage\__init__.py", line 1186, in _storage_error_handler
    return _general_error_handler(http_error)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\azure\__init__.py", line 551, in _general_error_handler
    http_error.respbody.decode('utf-8-sig'))
WindowsAzureError: Unknown error (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:898a6c60-0001-0094-2b99-d6da0d000000 Time:2015-08-14T13:58:54.9779810Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'DAAfD/aLQHqljUS35p7CoX+JBc5lyrPr1twQIQEW0HI='
 is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT

application/octet-stream Charset=UTF-8
```

Is there any possibilities to resolve this error?

This is my code changes in the module given by SDK.

```
def append_block_blob_from_file(self, container_name, blob_name, stream,
                             count=None, content_encoding=None,
                             content_language=None, content_md5=None,
                             cache_control=None,
                             x_ms_blob_content_type=None,
                             x_ms_blob_content_encoding=None,
                             x_ms_blob_content_language=None,
                             x_ms_blob_content_md5=None,
                             x_ms_blob_cache_control=None,
                             x_ms_meta_name_values=None,
                             x_ms_lease_id=None, progress_callback=None,
                             max_connections=1, max_retries=5, retry_wait=1.0):

    _validate_not_none('container_name', container_name)
    _validate_not_none('blob_name', blob_name)
    _validate_not_none('stream', stream)

    if count and count < self._BLOB_MAX_DATA_SIZE:
        if progress_callback:
            progress_callback(0, count)

        data = stream.read(count)
        self.put_blob(container_name,
                      blob_name,
                      data,
                      'AppendBlob',
                      content_encoding,
                      content_language,
                      content_md5,
                      cache_control,
                      x_ms_blob_content_type,
                      x_ms_blob_content_encoding,
                      x_ms_blob_content_language,
                      x_ms_blob_content_md5,
                      x_ms_blob_cache_control,
                      x_ms_meta_name_values,
                      x_ms_lease_id)

        if progress_callback:
            progress_callback(count, count)
    else:
        self.put_blob(
            container_name,
            blob_name,
            None,
            'AppendBlob',
            content_encoding,
            content_language,
            content_md5,
            cache_control,
            x_ms_blob_content_type,
            x_ms_blob_content_encoding,
            x_ms_blob_content_language,
            x_ms_blob_content_md5,
            x_ms_blob_cache_control,
            x_ms_meta_name_values,
            x_ms_lease_id,
        )

        _upload_blob_chunks(
            self,
            container_name,
            blob_name,
            count,
            self._BLOB_MAX_CHUNK_DATA_SIZE,
            stream,
            max_connections,
            max_retries,
            retry_wait,
            progress_callback,
            x_ms_lease_id,
            _AppendBlobChunkUploader,
        )

        self.put_block_list(
            container_name,
            blob_name,
            block_ids,
            content_md5,
            x_ms_blob_cache_control,
            x_ms_blob_content_type,
            x_ms_blob_content_encoding,
            x_ms_blob_content_language,
            x_ms_blob_content_md5,
            x_ms_meta_name_values,
            x_ms_lease_id,
        )
```

and i defined the below code in **Init**.py

```
class _AppendBlobChunkUploader(_BlobChunkUploader):
def _append_chunk(self, chunk_offset, chunk_data):
    range_id = url_quote(_encode_base64('{0:032d}'.format(chunk_offset)))
    self.blob_service.put_block(
        self.container_name,
        self.blob_name,
        chunk_data,
        range_id,
        x_ms_lease_id=self.x_ms_lease_id,x_ms_blob_condition_maxsize=4194304,x_ms_blob_condition_appendpos=chunk_offset
    )
    return range_id
```

Please Note two additional parameters at the end. I included this after referring the api reference. Also modified the version as 
X_MS_VERSION = '2015-02-21'

Ref Link:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt427365.aspx

Comment: I looked up source code for Azure SDK for Python here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/azure/storage/blobservice.py and I could not find append_block_blob_from_file function in the SDK. Can you tell us from which SDK are you using?

Comment: As i said earlier, i modified the python module and created this append_block_blob_from_file function just like put_block_blob_from_file. I Included all the needed changes in __init__.py and the other supporting files.

Comment: Please include your code in that case.

Comment: Please find my code changes in the module, updated question.

Comment: I suspect some changes in signature generation procedure please help.

Comment: I see .... you are working with `Append Blobs` announced recently. Did you modify put_block function as well?

Comment: Yes. I modified the put_block function and added the new request headers x-ms-blob-condition-maxsize and x-ms-blob-condition-appendpos.

Comment: But did you change the "comp" querystring parameter?

Comment: Thanks for the advice on comp querystring. I missed it earlier and now I created a new method append_block where I am passing the value appendblock for the query string comp.  Also the class _AppendBlobChunkUploader uses the newly created append_block method. Unfortunately, I am getting the same error.

Comment: May I suggest an alternative? Instead of making changes in the core SDK, I would suggest you create a Shared Access Signature in your application for append blob and use HTTP Libraries to invoke Storage REST API and get the job done. The reason why I say this is by changing the Core SDK, there's a chance you may end up messing Block/Page blobs functionality and down the road when new SDK comes with native support for Append Blobs, you may have to do a lot more work to revert back your changes. You may want to think about this approach.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and suggestion. I will try and update you ASAP...

Comment: When you create SAS, don't use SDK as there are some changes in SAS creation at the API level. Make sure you write your own code to create SAS token using this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn140255.aspx. HTH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you didn't provide the `put_block` function details from your description. I checked the Python SDK, I didn't find the `put_block` function supports those two parameters: `x_ms_blob_condition_maxsize`  and `x_ms_blob_condition_appendpos` in `BlobService` class. However, for your scenarios, I suggest you can use Azure Blob REST API to append your block as Gaurav's said. 
At the same time, from your error message, I am sure your signature has something wrong.
I have use a simple code to construct the signature string, please refer to it:

```
import urllib
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64
import urllib.request
from wsgiref.handlers import format_date_time
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime
account_name='****'
account_key='*****'
account_container='***'
file_name='**'
file_path='**'
request_url='https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob?comp=appendblock' 
#https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob?comp=appendblock  Put
blobLength=0
blockID='**'
#create the authorization header
#how to encode and decode signtostring 
def createAuthorizationHeader(canonicalizedString):
    storage_account_key = base64.b64decode(account_key)
    byte_canonicalizedString=canonicalizedString.encode('utf-8')
    signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(key=storage_account_key,msg=byte_canonicalizedString, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest())
    print(signature)
    authorization_str="SharedKey "+account_name+":"+signature.decode('utf-8')
    print(authorization_str)
    return authorization_str


#Construction Sign
def constructSTS(http_verb,Content_Encoding='',Content_Language='',Content_MD5='',Content_Type='',Date='',
                 If_Modified_Since='',If_Match='',If_None_Match='',length='',
                 If_Unmodified_Since='',Range='',CanonicalizedHeaders='',CanonicalizedResource=''):
    StringToSign=http_verb+'\n'+Content_Encoding+'\n'+Content_Language+'\n'+Content_MD5+'\n'+Content_Type+'\n'+Date+'\n'+If_Modified_Since+'\n'+If_Match+'\n'+If_None_Match+'\n'+length+'\n'+If_Unmodified_Since+'\n'+Range+'\n'+CanonicalizedHeaders+CanonicalizedResource;
    print(StringToSign)
    return StringToSign


#Construction Canonicalized headers
def constructCanonicalizedHeaders(date):    
    CanonicalizedHeader="x-ms-date:"+date+"\nx-ms-version:2015-02-21\nx-ms-lease-id:"+blockID+"\nms-blob-condition-appendpos:"+youroffset+"\nx-ms-blob-condition-maxsize:4194304\n"
    print(CanonicalizedHeader)
    return CanonicalizedHeader

#Construction  Canonicalized Resource
def constructCanonicalizedResource():
    canonicalizedResource="/"+account_name+"/"+account_container+"/"+file_name+"\ncomp:appendblock"
    print(canonicalizedResource)
    return canonicalizedResource

#get current date
def getCurrentDate():
    now = datetime.now()
    stamp = mktime(now.timetuple())
    date=format_date_time(stamp)
    return date
#Create http request
def createHttpRequest():
    date=getCurrentDate()
    r=urllib.request.Request(request_url)    
    canonicalizedString=constructSTS("PUT",CanonicalizedHeaders=constructCanonicalizedHeaders(date),CanonicalizedResource=constructCanonicalizedResource(),length=blobLength)
    print(canonicalizedString)
    r.add_header('x-ms-version','2015-02-21');
    r.add_header('Authorization',createAuthorizationHeader(canonicalizedString))
    r.add_header('x-ms-date',date)
    r.add_header('Content-Length',blobLength)
    r.add_header('x-ms-lease-id',blockID)
    r.add_header("x-ms-blob-condition-appendpos",youroffset)
    r.add_header("x-ms-blob-condition-maxsize",4194304)
```

You should get your blockblob length and send blockblob data to server using this request.

Answer (score 2):

just in case someone else comes across the same issue, here is a [link](https://github.com/squillace/staging/blob/master/articles/storage/storage-python-how-to-use-blob-storage.md) with an example how to append from python

```
from azure.storage.blob import AppendBlobService

append_blob_service = AppendBlobService(account_name='myaccount', account_key='mykey')

# The same containers can hold all types of blobs
append_blob_service.create_container('mycontainer')

# Append blobs must be created before they are appended to
append_blob_service.create_blob('mycontainer', 'myappendblob')
append_blob_service.append_blob_from_text('mycontainer', 'myappendblob', u'Hello, world!')

append_blob = append_blob_service.get_blob_to_text('mycontainer', 'myappendblob')
```

Comment: The SDK also contains some samples: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/samples/blob/append_blob_usage.py